# Tensorflow complaining about placeholder after model restore

Tags: tensorflow

I am having a problem with Tensorflow restoring models. I have a script that generates several models, based on a set of training files. These models are created with their own variable scopings, using

```py
tf.variable_scope(myPrefix).
```

After training, I am able to restore the models using

```py
tf.train.Saver(model_vars).restore(sess, model)
```

with model_vars computed as

```py
all_vars = tf.all_variables()                                                                                  
model_vars=[k for k in all_vars if k.name.startswith(myPrefix)]
```

While the models do seem to load, running them produces a Placeholder-error (see below, `85314_tr_10` is my prefix).

I am pretty sure I do not skip any placeholders. The model just has two (`x` and `y`) and these are used by the `eval` call I make:

```py
predictions = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: test_data, y:test_labels})
```

Here is the error trace:

```py
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1076] 0x2ea0e60 Compute status: Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor '85314_tr_10/Placeholder' with dtype float
         [[Node: 85314_tr_10/Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../prediction/views.py", line 507, in <module>
    predict("","85314","True","2015-11-12T09:08:00Z","2015-11-12T10:08:00Z")
  File "../prediction/views.py", line 472, in predict
    predictions= prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: test_data,y:test_labels}, session=sess)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 460, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2910, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 368, in run
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 444, in _do_run
    e.code)
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: try to name all the variables / placeholders to make sure you see which placeholder is giving problems

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio for your comment. I managed to get it working by bringing the model creation directly under the scope of the placeholders I use during the prediction step. Now, variables x and y are in the same 'closure' as their references. Not sure why this works, I am still on the steep part of the learning path here.

Comment: @fabrizioM: btw, that's an excellent idea that I will use in the future: x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1024, 1024),name="myName")

Comment: do you have any insight as to whats going on here? Having a similar issue after restore