# Tensorflow complains about missing feed_dict during graph restore

Tags: tensorflow, feed, restore

I've built a CNN for image classification. During training I've saved several checkpoints. The data is fed through a feed_dictionary into the network.

Now I want to restore the model which fails and I cant figure out why. The important lines of code are as follows:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():

....

if checkpoint_dir is not None:
    checkpoint_saver = tf.train.Saver()
    session_hooks.append(tf.train.CheckpointSaverHook(checkpoint_dir,
                                                      save_secs=flags.save_interval_secs,
                                                      saver=checkpoint_saver))
....

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
        save_summaries_steps=flags.save_summaries_steps,
        hooks=session_hooks,
        config=tf.ConfigProto(
            log_device_placement=flags.log_device_placement)) as mon_sess:

    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
    if checkpoint and checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path:

        # restoring from the checkpoint file
        checkpoint_saver.restore(mon_sess, checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path)

        global_step_restore = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
        print("Model restored from checkpoint: global_step = %s" % global_step_restore)
```

The Line "checkpoint_saver.restore" throws an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in **exit**
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_images' with dtype float
     [[Node: input_images = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Any knows how to solve this? Why do I need a filled feed_dictionary just for restoring the graph?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

This is the code of the restore method of the saver object:

```
  def restore(self, sess, save_path):
    """Restores previously saved variables.

    This method runs the ops added by the constructor for restoring variables.
    It requires a session in which the graph was launched.  The variables to
    restore do not have to have been initialized, as restoring is itself a way
    to initialize variables.

    The `save_path` argument is typically a value previously returned from a
    `save()` call, or a call to `latest_checkpoint()`.

    Args:
      sess: A `Session` to use to restore the parameters.
      save_path: Path where parameters were previously saved.
    """
    if self._is_empty:
      return
    sess.run(self.saver_def.restore_op_name,
             {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
```

What I don't get: Why is the graph executed immediately? Am I using the wrong method? I just want to restore all trainable vars.

Comment: Name all variables and placeholders. Is this helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793978/tensorflow-complaining-about-placeholder-after-model-restore

Comment: All vars are named. The input feed for my image tensor is missing. I think the problem is caused by the combined usage of MonitoredTrainingSession and a feed_dict. MonitoredTrainingSession is intended to be used for larger setups and maybe not compatible with feed dictionarys?!?. I'm trying to build a test case for my custom "training framework". Therefor I want to keep the example model light weighted (use a feed_dict rather than an import queue)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was cause by a SessionRunHook for process logging:

original hook:

```
class _LoggerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
  """Logs loss and runtime."""

  def begin(self):
    self._step = -1

  def before_run(self, run_context):
    self._step += 1
    self._start_time = time.time()
    return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(loss)  # Asks for loss value.

  def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
    duration = time.time() - self._start_time
    loss_value = run_values.results
    if self._step % 5 == 0:
      num_examples_per_step = FLAGS.batch_size
      examples_per_sec = num_examples_per_step / duration
      sec_per_batch = float(duration)

      format_str = ('%s: step %d, loss = %.2f (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f '
                    'sec/batch)')
      print (format_str % (datetime.now(), self._step, loss_value,
                           examples_per_sec, sec_per_batch))
```

modified hook:

```
class _LoggerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    """Logs loss and runtime."""

    def __init__(self, flags, loss_op):
        self._flags = flags
        self._loss_op = loss_op
        self._start_time = time.time()

    def begin(self):
        self._step = 0

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        if self._step == 0:
            run_args = None
        else:
            run_args = tf.train.SessionRunArgs(self._loss_op)

        return run_args

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):

        if self._step > 0:
            duration_n_steps = time.time() - self._start_time
            loss_value = run_values.results
            if self._step % self._flags.log_every_n_steps == 0:
                num_examples_per_step = self._flags.batch_size

                duration = duration_n_steps / self._flags.log_every_n_steps
                examples_per_sec = num_examples_per_step / duration
                sec_per_batch = float(duration)

                format_str = ('%s: step %d, loss = %.2f (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f '
                              'sec/batch)')
                print(format_str % (datetime.now(), self._step, loss_value,
                                    examples_per_sec, sec_per_batch))

                self._start_time = time.time()
        self._step += 1
```

Explanation:

The logging is now skiped for the first iteration. So the session.run, which is executed by Saver.restore(..) doens't requiere a filled feed dictionary anymore.